# How to transform a string which is a multiple categorical response variable from with SQL query or Python

Tags: python, sql

I have in a SQL query a column that I want to use as a response for a model.

It can contain x categories;

```
Variable
-------

ProductA, ProductB

ProductC, ProductZ, ProductB

ProductA, ProductC

ProductA
```

I want to transform it into a response variable, what would be the best approach and how could I do it?

For example (for the first column) something like this would make sense for a recommender?

```
Product A | Product B | Product C

1  |  1  | 0
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `case`.  In standard SQL, you would use:

```
select (case when ', ' || variable || ', ' like '%, ProductA, %' then 1 else 0 end) as has_productA,
       (case when ', ' || variable || ', ' like '%, ProductB, %' then 1 else 0 end) as has_productB,
       (case when ', ' || variable || ', ' like '%, ProductC, %' then 1 else 0 end) as has_productC
```

Note the use of the delimiters around the product names.  This is important so `'ProductA'` does not match `'ProductAB'`.